SVN only works on sudo on Mac Sonoma
I have the brew subversion installed.
svn, version 1.14.3 (r1914484)
   compiled Dec  9 2023, 13:27:10 on arm-apple-darwin23.5.0

Copyright (C) 2023 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.10 (compiled with 1.3.10)
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Mac OS X Keychain

The past 3 months i'd use svn commands (svn info, svn checkout, svn log...) without use sudo.
But yesterday if i do:
svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix
returns:
svn: E175003: The server at 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix' does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol
svn list -v http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix
returns:
svn: E130005: XML Parsing failed: Unexpected root element 'options-response'
but, if i do this with sudo:
sudo svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix
Path: felix
URL: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix
Relative URL: ^/felix
Repository Root: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
Repository UUID: 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68
Revision: 1918078
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: pauls
Last Changed Rev: 1890953
Last Changed Date: 2021-06-21 18:44:32 -0300 (Mon, 21 Jun 2021)

I tried:

Update the system (actually last version: Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
Reinstall svn and sqlite
Restart the machine.
Chown on /opt/homebrew/Cellar
Already have the admin group on sudo visudo and my user are on it.
That's not a proxy problem, i tried on my personal network.


Does it depend on a library which is incorrectly installed so that only root has access?

@tripleee like i said, i tried do chown to my user on Cellar folder on /opt/homebrew and tried to reinstall svn using homebrew and tried a fresh new install with macports, same error. Do you know anything else I can try?
